# Restore RDS Snapshot from console or CLI is way faster than cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am writing some automation to create a duplicate of the of my AWS production environment for devs and QA to test with. I am using a bash script calling a AWS cli with AWS Cloudformation templates.

When I do this with Cloudformation, it creates the DB and then RDS spends 7 hours modifying it with the "Applying modification to allocated storage" log until CloudFormation fails with "DBInstance testaedb did not stabilize" and starts to roll back, which also fails.

If I create the same RDS instance from the console, using the same arguments, it takes ~7 mins to create the RDS instance and become active. I just ran a test this morning and the same is true if I create it using the CLI tools.

Here is the CloudFormation template snippet:

```
  AccountsRds:
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Sub '${EnvName}aedb'
      DBSnapshotIdentifier: !Sub '${AccountsSnapshot}'
      DBInstanceClass: 'db.t3.xlarge'
      DBSubnetGroupName:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub '${NetworkStackName}-RdsSubnetGroupId'
      AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: 'true'
      PubliclyAccessible: 'false'
      VPCSecurityGroups:
      - !GetAtt AccountsRdsSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

and here is the CLI snippet:

```
aws rds restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot \
 --region ${AE_REGION} \
 --db-instance-identifier "${AE_ENV_NAME}"aedb \
 --db-snapshot-identifier ${AE_DB_SNAPSHOT_ID} \
 --db-instance-class db.t3.xlarge \
 --db-subnet-group-name ${AE_DB_SUBNET_GROUP_NAME} \
 --no-publicly-accessible \
 --auto-minor-version-upgrade \
 --vpc-security-group-ids ${AE_DB_SECURITY_GROUP}
```

I expected that CloudFormtation and the CLI would take the same amount of time. Any idea why Cloudformation would take 7 hours? My DB is not that big, 250GB.

Comment: Was the snapshot made from an instance with Provisioned IOPS?

Comment: It was not. It came from an instance with just the standard SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the problem has been identified by AWS support. According to them, the default `StorageType` for an RDS instance is different depending how it is provisioned:

- CLI command: `gp2`
- Web console: `gp2`
- CloudFormation: Magnetic disk

So, it was failing because the performance of the magnetic disk is not enough to handle the Snapshot restore.

The solution is to simply include the `StorageType` in your Cloudformation template and it will provision with similar speed as the CLI command.